# Twitterの認証が解除されていることを検知する

Tags: android, twitter4j

下記のサイトを参考にTwitter機能をアプリに実装し、ログインと投稿ができるようになりました。

http://qiita.com/gabu/items/f6f39900fd5e449045f9
※ちなみにログインボタンを押して認証が終わると、定型文をそのままタイムラインにツイートするという仕様に変更してます。

しかし、TwitterのサイトでアプリとTwitterの認証を解除して再びログインボタンを押すと、ログイン画面に移らずそのまま投稿しようとして投稿が失敗してしまいます。
上記のサイトのやり方では`sharedpreferences`を使ってアクセストークンを保存してそれをずっと使っているからだと思うのですが、ではアプリとTwitterの連携が解除された時に処理を行わせようとしてもやり方がわかりません。どうすればTwitterの認証が解除されていることを検知することができるでしょうか？
すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> どうすればTwitterの認証が解除されていることを検知することができるでしょうか？

認証が解除されていることを検知するには、保存したアクセストークンを用いて Twitter の API を実際に叩いてみる必要があります。

連携が解除されている場合はエラーが発生するので、そのエラーをみて判断する必要があります。
詳細は [Error Codes & Responses HTTP Status Codes](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) を確認してください

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、「保存したアクセストークンを用いてTwitterのAPIを叩く」ということですが、これはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @kojianu 「定型文をそのままタイムラインにツイートする」ということがまさに Twitter の API を叩くということになります。他にも [REST APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) に API 群が定義されていています。 twitter4j を使用している際は REST APIs を叩いている意識はないかもしれませんが、内部で行われています。 twitter4j は詳しくないのですが、 `twitter4j.api` パッケージ内のクラスは REST APIs を叩いているようです。

Comment: ツイートしてTwitterExceptionを確認したところ、「code - 89」という行を見つけました。リンク先を合わせて確認すると「Invalid or expired token」と書いてあり、この辺りを修正すれば良さそうな気がするので、この辺りで頑張ってみたいと思います。

Comment: このあたりも参考になるかも知れません http://outofmem.tumblr.com/post/83694084907/twitter4j-twitter

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。リンク先の方法で無事エラーを拾えることができました。誠にありがとうございます。